# Count length of user-visible string for zsh prompt

Tags: zsh

I'd like to put my current `git` branch into my multi-line ZSH prompt. However, this messes up the two lines - I'd like them to line up nicely.

```
┌─(simont@charmander:s000)─[master *]────────────────
───(~  )─┐  
└─(127:15:44)──                       ──(Sat,May12)─┘
```

should be:

```
┌─(simont@charmander:s000)─[master *]─────────(~  )─┐  
└─(127:15:44)──                       ──(Sat,May12)─┘
```

The `git` branch is grabbed from an `oh-my-zsh` function, `git_prompt_info()`, which gives me the branch, dirty status, and a bunch of prompt-escapes to color things nicely.

How do I count the characters that will be *visibly* inserted into the ZSH prompt - not the prompt escape sequences?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that the prompt-escaped string is stored in a variable `FOO`, this will count only user-visible characters:

```
FOO=$(git_prompt_info)
local zero='%([BSUbfksu]|([FK]|){*})'
FOOLENGTH=${#${(S%%)FOO//$~zero/}}
```

This comes from [this `.zshrc`](http://ruderich.org/simon/config/zshrc).

This is a *rough* explanation of why it works, liberally quoting from [`man zshexpn`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn), section `PARAMETER EXPANSION`. I'm not 100% sure of the details, so, if you're using this to develop your own equivalent, read the relevant `man zshall` sections.

Working from the line `FOOLENGTH=${#${(S%%)FOO//$~zero/}}`, we've got a number of bits. Going from the inside out:

1. `$~zero`: The `~` ensures that `zero`, which we've defined as `'%([BSUbfksu]|([FB]|){*})'`, is treated as a pattern rather than as a plain string.
2. `${(S%%)FOO//$~zero/}`: This matches `${name//pattern/repl}`:

   > Replace  the longest possible match of pattern in the expansion of parameter name by string repl

   Note that we don't have a `repl`; we replace the longest possible match of `pattern` with nothing, thereby removing it.

   `(S%%)FOO` conducts an expansion on `FOO` with several flags set. I don't quite follow it.
3. `${#${(S%%)FOO//$~zero/}}`: `${#spec}` will substitute the length in characters of the result of the substitution `spec`, if `spec` is a substitution. In our case, `spec` is the result of the substitution `${(S%%)FOO//$~zero/}`; so this basically returns the length of characters in the result of the regular expression `s/zero//` on `FOO`, where `zero` is the pattern above.

Comment: `(S)` makes matching non-greedy thus turning “longest possible match” into “shortest possible match” (without it `{*}` in a pattern will turn thing like `%F{blue}%M%F{yellow}%#%f` into just `%#`, while it should turn it into `%M%#`), `(%%)` performs prompt expansion on the string, following PROMPT_* options. Note: this method should be avoided if PROMPT string contains a command with some side-effects: for example, if you want to use it to count how often the prompt is shown. Most of time you won’t suffer from this.

Comment: And yes, all `(*)` flags are described in PARAMETER EXPANSION section of `man zshexpn`.

Comment: @ZyX Thanks. I saw the explanation for `S` in the `zshexpn` page, but wasn't sure how it fitted in.

Comment: Does not work with date formatting, like `%D{%a %b %d, %I:%M:%S%P}`

Comment: @beardtree True. But the string returned by that date format will not include prompt-specific characters (such as color codes). You can count it using `date='%D{%a %b %d, %I:%M:%S%P}', length=${#${date}}}`.

Comment: @beardtree If you're trying to get your prompt to line up, [this](http://aperiodic.net/phil/prompt/) might be of interest to you - it's got a brief discussion on the way he did it.

Comment: Just mentioned: your variant is not going to output width of a number of Unicode strings: Unicode contains things like fullwidth characters (they occupy two display cells), diacritics (most of time they occupy no display cells) and tab. Either three are treated by `${#}` as one character, but zsh recognizes their display width correctly. There are also characters which have ambiguous width (this may mean that their width depends on terminal settings) (ambiguous == one or two display cells).

Comment: @ZyX Thanks for pointing that out - it's not an issue I have noticed (yet), or know how to fix - if I find some solution, I'll amend the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to do this with builtin zsh commands, but color information can be stripped with sed (as documented [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed)):

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
```

e.g.

```
plain_str=$(git_prompt_info | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g")
```

Which would strip all escape sequences from the string. The length is now simply:

```
echo $#plain_str
```